# How to run several Pipeline builds at the same time?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

We have several build pipelines, not releated to each other, at the moment and some need to be running at the same time, but the current setup is that only one can build at the time and others will be queued as can be seen here

[image]

We would like to avoid this so that several can run at the same time but is this possible with our current setup of Parallel agents:

[image]

where we have 1 free parallel job and 16 VS Enterprise subscriptions. Is it necessary to buy more parallel jobs or is there a way to run multiple pipelines simultaneously with the current setup?

Comment: How many self-hosted agent have you configured, so far? Visual Studio Enterprise subscribers get one self-hosted parallel job as a subscriber benefit.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot you have shared, I see that you have 5 Microsoft Hosted parallel jobs and 17 self hosted parallel jobs.

In order to use self hosted parallel jobs, you need to install ADO agents to the machines managed by you. After that you can use these agent for your parallel jobs.